# Setting Events in a class that utilize a later mentioned Prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-events

When I reach the `console.log()` its returning window.

How can I get the element under consideration?

```
let builder = function(){
    this.box = $(`<div id="box" class="box">`);
    this.inputcontainer = $(`<div id="inputcontainer" class="inputcontainer">`).appendTo(this.box);
    this.textarea = $(`<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>`).appendTo(this.inputcontainer);
    this.textarea.on("change keyup keydown input paste", this.postmsg);
    this.chat.appendTo($('body'));
}

//someothercode

builder.prototype.postmsg = (e) => {
    console.log(this); // returns window when I need it to be referencing textarea
}

let instance = new builder();
```

Comment: No `this` in arrow functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
builder.prototype.postmsg = function(e){
    console.log(this.textarea);
}
```

Comment: Comes back as undefined

Comment: I think it's beacause of the arow function postmsg, declare it as a normal function

Comment: It's been the purpose of arrow function, it let you to get the this reference of the last parent classic function, in your case it was window